# Having trouble viewing DEM in 3D view

Tags: qgis, dem, 3d, sql-view

I am trying to view my DEM of terrain for a project in the 3D viewfinder, but having some difficulty. I can see it as flat terrain, but when I turn on DEM for the interpolation it disappears in the viewfinder.

Does it have to be on a certain projection?

I am running the most current version of QGIS on my machine.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this problem? I am having the same problem now....